# MySQL Database Schema - General Questions

Tags: mysql, database, generics, schema

please note that I'm a noob at database design as I have never done it.

I have a website set up for a online game created in Java. When a player logs out of the game, I have it add a row (or update a row if it already exists) in a table named "highscores" in a database named "highscores"...

I have a highscores page on my website that uses php to pull data from the highscores table and organize it into a html table so players can see their scores and everything works great. I also have forums on my website by installing fluxBB (a forum system) and modified it to my liking.

So in my PHPMyAdmin, I have a total of 5 databases: **information_schema**, **performance_schema**, **mysql**, **highscores** and **forums**.
The first three databases were added when I installed phpmyadmin and I haven't touched them. The **forums** database I made when installing the forums; it requested a database to create tables in so I made a new database to put all the tables into.

So I have some questions...

1. Is my database set up how a typical website would do it? If not, how would a typical website with highscores & forums have their databases set up? Do they have one database for their website and then one database for their game?
2. If I want to add statistics about the server like "x amount of accounts have been created" or "x amount of players are currently online", where would I store this information? I was thinking about renaming the highscores database to "game" (or the name of my game) and then inside that would be a "highscores" table and a "server_statistics" table. Is that good? But the "server_statistics" table would only have one row which holds the statistics... is that normal?
3. If I want to add a poll to my website, would I make a new database called "poll"? Or should I have a database called like "website" where I would put all website-related data in? But I have a "forums" database so what would I do with that?
4. How do websites publish news normally? If the article is stored in the database, how do they publish news so that it appears on the home page? And would there be a "news" database then?

It's hard to find generic questions online... I've tried searching but please don't just link me to an article because it's probably not fit to my situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you should ask every question separatly. You more likely receive a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since we are talking about a relatively small database, holding information about a website and a game, it would be preferable that you used a `website` or `game` database and split the different information across tables.

The think you don't specify right here is how do you keep the highscores? Are those linked to a users table, a forum user or just a name field in the highscores table?

1. Since you are using an external forum system i would keep that database as it is and just create a second one as suggested above for use by my game and my website.
2. Statistics like most users online and number of accounts would not be saved in the database as that would create unnecessary and redundant calls to the `DBMS` which is not optimal. Those would most probably be created on the fly or even better using a cron job and create a cached statistic that will be shown to the user even if that number is a couple of minutes old.
3. Again having a `website` database, you would then create additional tables as needed inside the `website` db and leave the `forums` database alone as is.
4. Most of the sites you'll see will have a central database that will have a number of tables ie. `users` , `news`,`comments`,`reviews`, etc.

The news table schema could be in the form of:

```
id             int   auto_increment & primary key
title          varchar(*)
content        text or big varchar according to your needs
posted_on      datetime or timestamp
posted_by      int key representing the authors id
```

In general if you are just starting out with databases and are interested in learning more about best practices, i would first read a few books/articles around the subject which will in turn lead to more specialized subjects such database relationships, normalization and best practices.

Besides that you will find it very interesting to check out how other structure their databases and that can be easily done by inspecting some of the open-source projects available online like joomla, wordpress and others. When you start looking around it will all come a lot easier.

Comment: The rows in the highscores table has the player's username + 36 "scores". So there is a total of 37 values in each row. The forums are separate from the game (they need to register again) and I don't mind this. I don't know how I would get statistics from my server to be displayed on the website if I don't store it in a database :S My game has a server & a client both made in Java. When the server is running, people can join through a client. The server can get the amount of people online but how would I get that value do be displayed on the website by not storing it on the database first?

Comment: If i get it correct you have `highscores` table with `username` `game1score` `game2score` ...? For statistics I wouldn't use a database for simple numbers like that, that change constantly and are shown alot of times. You could even save that in a simple flat `text` or `XML` file

Comment: Yeah, that's how my highscores are set up.

I think I got all my answers now and I'll try setting it up to store and read the statistics from a text file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not the best way to save the highscores in my opinion. I'd suggest you read a little about databases and for example consider what happens if you want to add another new game? Where are the scores for the 37th game be stored?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to do this in order:

1. There is no such thing as a typical website there are software packages that have been designed to use certain schema and that's what they use.  The setups vary based on the need, this may be 1 database with multiple tables, or multiple databases.
2. You would need to have a table somewhere that monitors your users logging on and off as well as start dates for certain accounts.  If you are separating forums and highscores for some reason I would suggest you separate the user management too.
3. Depends on your implementation.  If you are using someone else's product you may have a database defined for you or not defined at all just displayed on your site and data to be stored elsewhere.
4. I am not even sure what you mean.  When news are stored they may be stored in a database in which case the text is retrieved for the article and formatted for display, or it could be a file on the server and based on the ID and link information stored in the database and your script simply retrieves and displays it.

In general there are best practices on normalization of databases, which you should look at for your site.  But first I would suggest examining a relationship you have between your forum and the game.  If they are indivisible from each other namely if a person plays the game they participate in the forume and vice versa then it might be better for these databases to actually be one.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant by question 4 is if a website retrieves the articles from a database, then to add news to the website you would manually go into the database and add a row with the news article? That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Why doesn't it sound correct? If you think about it an article is nothing but a piece of `text`, maybe a `varchar` for the title, a `datetime` for the `posted_time`, an `int` for the `user_id` and that can easily be saved in a row with a unique id ofcourse

Comment: Ok :S it just seems odd going into phpmyadmin and inserting a row to make a news post? I was thinking of making a forum called "News" and when a topic is made in there from an administrator, the front page gets the post and puts it onto the front page.

Comment: Dont confuse the two. They don't go into `phpmyadmin` and add a new row for a news post. There are commercial or custom made systems called `CMS` as in Content management systems which are responsible for updating the database record for `CRUD` operations. Google `CMS` to get an idea of what i'm talking about